# Mmenu light JS and Angular 8

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Does anyone know how to run the Mmenu light JS plugin into an Angular 8 project?
I am talking about where to place the 'mmenu-light.js' code.
Any advice would be of any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. open `angular.json` file
2. and in the `"scripts": []`
3. Add 'mmenu-light.js'

Answer (score 0):

thanks for answering. I followed your advice on adding mmenu-light into angular.json file.
Also I placed some code inside .ts file and ngOnInit section,
var menu = new MmenuLight(
document.querySelector( '#menu' ),
'all'
);

but I get this:
error TS2304: Cannot find name 'MmenuLight'.
var menu = new MmenuLight(

Any advice would be appreciated, thanks!!